# Calling an id in an xml file in your class

Tags: android, xml, if-statement, imageview

How can I detect whether or not an Image View has a picture in it upon a button click.  I had a class that displays a picture and some results, but I don't want the user to be able to access those results (pushing the button) until the results have been written to that class.

So, I figured I needed to check to see if there was a picture displayed in the ImageView yet.

So something like:

```
        case R.id.previous_box:
            if (R.id.photoResultView == null){
                            //throw up a dialog box saying they need to snap a pic first.

            }


            Intent j = new Intent(DTF.this, Result.class);
            startActivity(j);
            return;
```

but obviouslt R.id.photoResultView == null isn't the right way to do it...anyone know how?

Tanks!

EDIT:  Line 184

```
    if (photoResultView.getDrawable() == null) {
```

EDIT:

```
        case R.id.previous_box:

            if (photoResultView.getDrawable() == null) {
                showToast(DTF.this, "You have to take a picture first");
                return;
            }
            Intent j = new Intent(main.this, Result.class);
            startActivity(j);
            return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, instead of the `if` block you currently have, this:

```
ImageView photoResultView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoResultVew);
if (photoResultView.getDrawable() == null) {
    //throw dialog
}
```

[`ImageView.getDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29) returns either a Drawable or null (if there is no Drawable set).

Basically, say you have something like this:

```
public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {   
    ImageView photoResultView; //this creates a class variable
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //this assigns it to the photoResultView you defined in your XML
        photoResultView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoResultView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put that in, but it closes with an unforced error - any ideas?

Comment: the photoResultView is null, it is not declared in the view hierarchy

Comment: it is just an imageview in an xml file, do I need to declare it in the class?

Comment: Sapp: No, you shouldn't. But you have set the ID in the XML with `android:id="@+id/photoResultView"`, correct?

Comment: yea - the id is there in the xml file

Comment: ok, then edit your post and mark which exactly is the line 184

Comment: This is in an onClickListener method with a switch for each button btw

Comment: so you haven't found any with a findViewById. A common error for this is in the onCreate/Prepare of dialogs - people forget to use dialog.findViewById and type just findViewById. Is that it ?

Comment: you mean here:   

ImageView photoResultView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoResultView);  ??

Comment: Ah, okay. Apps may know a better solution (how to access findViewByIds from inside a listener) but I would just move the `ImageView ...` line out of the listener and into `onCreate()`.

Comment: you mean like this:  protected static final ImageView photoResultView = null;?  I put that in my field, and still got the same error =/

Comment: Hmm? No, just move the line out of the listener as it is in my original answer, and move it into your onCreate() method somewhere.

Comment: do you have a setContentView() ? You need to specify an actual root element that will have this id. BTW static ImageView is a horrible thing to do, the explanation may be hard for you at the moment, so just take my words for granted and don't use the bad word "stat*c" anywhere, until you learn some more stuff :)

Comment: Ok, do I need to alter if (photoResultView.getDrawable() == null) {  because it is saying photoResultView cannot be resolved if I declare it in the onCreate method

Comment: I am not setting a content  view, I am using an intent actually - editing the OP to show the exact code for my box.

Comment: make it with class visibility, class A { private ImageView v; [functions] } and in on create v = find... Beware for statics.

Comment: Oh wait. So you're doing a separate listener outside of the method...I've seen it that way, but never done it that way myself, I always use an inline listener. Try declaring `ImageView photoResultView` as a class variable (outside of onCreate()) and then in onCreate(), put `photoResultView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photoResultView);`

Comment: sorry, I am a little lost at what you are saying apps - very new to this, as I am sure you can tell ;)

Comment: bahh, I tried that and there is still an NPE, I did ImageView photoResultView; as a variable and defined it in the onCreate method, using the code I showed in the edit and same problem =/

Comment: don't worry, I am answering while I wait the project to compile and I have nothing better to do during this time anyway :)
 EDIT: I will post it as an answer, because the comments can't break into new lines and it looks messy to read

Comment: right, that's exactly how I have it - one thing that might be super important, is the id-photoResultView is checking an xml file not associated with the main class.  I have my main.class, my result.class (which the button points to if there is a pic in it) and a resul.xml as the content View.

Comment: what? you mean that you have setContentView(A) and you are trying to access an id which is in a file B ???

Comment: right - the button is in my main class, and if the user clicks the button, the if statement checks to see if their is a picture in the result class, if there isn't, it won't goto that class, show the toast, and force the user to snap a pic before acccessing if that makes sense.

Comment: Sapp: The IDs don't even exist until that activity has been started, and has called the XML file on the results.class's setContentView();. That's like trying to see if a book has a particular word on, say, page 65, before turning to page 65 to look at it. :)

Comment: ohhhh ok - so there is no way to check if another xml has a picture attached to it until I actually access the xml file?  So I can't actually block the user from accessing that page (from clicking that button)?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are struggling for with the "picture in the result class" and so on, but when you give a setContentView, you can access only childs of the root view in that XML file. You can't find an ID from a different XML

Comment: I am not sure why you need this technique for "check if a picture is attached" , but for sure it is not what you are looking for

Comment: Well, I get the user to snap a photo, and then I show the photo on an ImageView in the result page.  I basically don't want the user to access that page until a photo has been snapped.  Once it has been snapped, they can check out the photo by clicking the button...I don't want the user to click the button and there be nothing on the page.

Comment: Ok, can't you determine if that photo has been snapped ? You are filling this ImageView with the photo anyway, until now you tried to check if the ImageView is null, can't you just check if the photo is null ?

Comment: right, but the photo won't be filled into the imageview until they click the snap photo button and snap a photo themself...once the photo is snapped it is displayed on the results page.  I just don't want them to be able to access that page until they have snapped the photo first - kind of a linear process.

Comment: It's impossible for that ImageView to have anything in it, ever, until the activity has been started, and the layout inflated (`setContentView()`). When they click the "snap photo" button, you are going to have to pass the resulting image into the results activity. You should be checking if your Image (Bitmap, probably) is null. You just can't access a page that hasn't been created yet, the XML is simply a structure - a blueprint of how to create the activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 private ImageView imageView;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_records);
   imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

 }

}
```